# SQL Server's bcp utility corrupts varbinary(max) data

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Binaries]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [SHA256] [varbinary](32) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [DeletedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

Commands:

```
bcp MyDb.dbo.Binaries format nul -f E:\format.fmt -T -n
bcp MyDb.dbo.Binaries OUT E:\Binaries.bcp -f E:\format.fmt -T
bcp MyDb.dbo.Binaries IN E:\Binaries.bcp -f E:\format.fmt -T
```

Format file:

```
14.0
6
1       SQLBIGINT           0       8       ""   1     Id                         ""
2       SQLBINARY           8       0       ""   2     Data                       ""
3       SQLBINARY           2       32      ""   3     SHA256                     ""
4       SQLDATETIME2        0       8       ""   4     CreatedDate                ""
5       SQLDATETIME2        1       8       ""   5     DeletedDate                ""
6       SQLBIT              1       1       ""   6     IsDeleted                  ""
```

`Data` column contains documents i.e. pdf files, after import files are corrupted (difference about 5-10%, files have smaller size).

Original database was restored from .bak file.

Server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019089) - 13.0.4206.0 (X64) Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro N 6.3 <X64> (Build 17134: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Can you post the format file you got from the first line? And what is your SQL version?

Comment: Added format file and server version.

Comment: I just ran your tests in 2012 and 2016 and the PDFs export fine, except that there is a string of characters prepended and appended at the end. Those characters of course originate from the `.fmt` file created for the table. So in my case, `bcp` spit out the table record, as requested. I cannot confirm your result of files being smaller than the originals. Edit your `.fmt` to exclude fields except the BLOB and it should export one to one. Unless of course I misread your question, and you meant that files are smaller than BLOBs. Then the reason is what I wrote earlier.

Comment: I've tried using C#/ADO.NET to export and import data (raw byte arrays) using file on disk and got exactly same problem, files were corrupted in the same way, byte-to-byte. I suspect that data is somehow modified during insert/select operation (encoded?), but I don't  have any idea why.

Comment: Is corruption occurring during the import, or export? I can also confirm that when inserting from `openrowset bulk` the correct number of bytes is entered into a BLOB.

Comment: I've tried `datalength(Data)` function on both systems, it returns 164695 bytes for both imported and original file, however there is size column in the old database and it has value 268030, which is correct. I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Try to import a new record using a brand new physical PDF file into the new DB. If you use `from openrowset (bulk ... single_blob)` the imported size should be the same as physical. Then look if your export suddenly works. This is a very reliable technology which I used for decades, so something is wrong with the code, or environment.

Comment: Finally I found the problem, old system was built using DevExpress framework, and it turns out that internally it uses compression (sometimes, smart!), so data was actually compressed ... Anyways, thanks for your help.